# Gulp + browserify + typescript - type expected

Tags: typescript, gulp, browserify

I am not able to run this script. Each time it throws me an error:

> -> % gulp compile-js [22:18:57] Using gulpfile ~/wwwdata/projects/site/gulpfile.js [22:18:57] Starting
>   'compile-js'...
>
> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ TS1110: app/Resources/src/tsc/Material.ts(22,19): TS1110: Type expected.

line 22 looks like this:

```
private _xhr: null | JQueryXHR;
```

if I change it to

```
private _xhr:any;
```

then I'm getting:

> TS1005: app/Resources/src/tsc/Material.ts(147,33): TS1005: '=' expected.

which is generated for the `for` loop in this method:

```
/** load threads/comments for current loaded material */
getThreads() {

    /** if there is no more threads to load just exit the function */
    if(this.isMoreThreads == false) {
        return;
    }

    let url = Routing.generate('comments', {
        type: this.materialType,
        id: this.materialId,
        page: this.page
    });


    if (this._xhr) {
        this._xhr.abort();
    }

    this._xhr = $.ajax(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        beforeSend: () => {
        },
        success: (response) => {

            if(!(response.hasOwnProperty('threads'))) {
                this.isMoreThreads = false;
                $(document.getElementById('loadMoreThreads')).remove();
                return;
            }

            //for (let thread in response.threads) { // <- if change 'of' to 'in' then there is no error
            for (let thread of response.threads) {
                let thr = new MaterialThread(thread);
                this.addThread = thr;

                this._commentsContainer.append(thr.render());
            }
        },
        error: () => {
            let act = confirm('Error has occurred. Refresh page?');
            if (act === true) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        },
        complete: () => {
            this._commentsContainer.find('#loading').fadeOut();
            this._xhr = null;
        }
    });
}
```

My `gulpfile.js`:

```
var tsconfig = {
    target: "es5",
    module: "commonjs",
    declaration: false,
    noImplicitAny: false,
    removeComments: true,
    noLib: false
};

gulp.task('compile-js', function() {
    var bundler = browserify({
        basedir: paths.typescript,
        debug: true,
    })
        .add(paths.typescript + '/index.ts')
        .plugin(tsify, tsconfig)
        .transform(debowerify);

    return bundler.bundle()
        .pipe(exorcist('/dupa/application.js.map'))
        .pipe(source('application.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/dupa'));
});
```

Comment: As I know, null is allowed only with void and undefined with the pipe operator. they are siblings types, and can only be assigned between then in declarations and other stuff like you trying to do.

Comment: @Fals, ok, let's change it to `any`. What about second error?

Comment: TS1005 means something is missing, if you can provide more code, we could help you to find the issue. A common mistake is assign something with **:** when we don't specify the type. Some of your properties before/after this one has an error.

Comment: Also, if you take a closer look, the line where the error occur changed to **(147,33)**, there's the new issue.

Comment: @Fals I have updated my question

Comment: (for of) =>If you are not targeting ES6 or above, the generated code assumes the property length exists on the object and that the object can be indexed via numbers e.g. obj[2]. So it is only supported on string and array for these legacy JS engines.

Comment: @Fals hope this is the last issue. I have changed `for` loop to `(for ... in)` but now I'm having problem with typings:
> TS1110: app/Resources/src/tsc/typings/jquery.d.ts(1491,54): TS1110: Type expected. I have set `noImplicitAny` to `false` but it didn't helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141589/discussion-between-fals-and-breq).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add exclude to your `tsconfig` file, to void this erro **TS1110: app/Resources/src/tsc/typings/jquery.d.ts(1491,54): TS1110**

```
var tsconfig = {
    target: "es5",
    module: "commonjs",
    declaration: false,
    noImplicitAny: false,
    removeComments: true,
    noLib: false,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings"
    ]
};
```

Comment: arghhh, now I'm having this issue:
> TS1153: 'let' declarations are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher.

Comment: @breq you shoul update your node to the latest version, and also your typescript version, I tried here some code with let targeting ES5 and went fine.

Comment: I'm using typescript v 2.2.2 and node v 4.2.6. Here is my actual gulpfile.js https://pastebin.com/1vwGc5Pz and my tsconfig.json https://pastebin.com/jHVx9e4G